# Isotope with BBQ

Tags: wordpress, jquery-isotope, jquery-bbq

i'm using the following implementation of isotope to include an isotope grid on my wordpress site that filters by tag, using three select menus. This all works great but can anyone give me some guidance on adding the BBQ plugin to enable me to link to predefined filters from other pages. I have tried a few variations but am not sure how to use my existing code alongside BBQ. Thanks for your help guys!

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
$container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector : '.item', 
    layoutMode : 'fitRows',

});

//Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
var $optionSets = $('.group'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('option');

$optionLinks.click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
// don't proceed if already selected
if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
  return false;
}
var $optionSet = $this.parents('.group');
$optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$this.addClass('selected');

//When an item is clicked, sort the items.
 var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });

return false;
});

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by link to  link to predefined filters from other pages? You need to provide more info. Also, FYI, BBQ was last updated 5 years ago so you may have issues related to this if you are intent on using it.

Comment: http://www.domain.com/?filter=option or something along those lines, so i can visit the isotope page from another link and the filters will already be applied. Hope that makes sense.